# React - add variable in URL for fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, url

I have a fetch:

```
fetch(`https://example/e1/e11/${variable1}?param=A1&include=metadata`, {
  "method": "GET"...
```

What is wrong to declarate the variable1 in this way?
With this it works:

```
https://example/e1/e11/$apple?param=A1&include=metadata
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: Agreed with @Andy, this a very common way of handling this.

Comment: Try adding an extra `$` along with the existing one.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong with that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
fetch(`https://example/e1/e11/' + variable1 + '?param=A1&include=metadata`, {
```

"method": "GET"...

Comment: Why? What's wrong with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: What is your browser?